# How to fix Heroku Openai Django Deployment Error?

Tags: python, django, heroku, openai-gym, openai-api

When deploying a new Heroku App Using a Django Docker Enviorment

Inside my requirments.txt

I have

```
openai==0.11.0
```

When doing

```
git push heroku master
```

During Build I get this Error

```
 Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1803 lines of output]
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
    Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [251 lines of output]
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C++ program. note: A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
      [end of output]
```

Any help really appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
RUN apk add g++ postgresql-dev cargo gcc python3-dev libffi-dev
```

To the Dockerfile.web fixed the issue